# Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "MailController"

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I want to sent an email with swiftmailer
this is my function in my mailController.php

```
public function newMail(Mail $mail){
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Accusé de réception')
            ->setFrom('hela.mejri@esprit.tn')
            ->setTo($mail->getEmail())
            ;

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

error : Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "UserBundle\Controller\MailController".

Comment: You controller inherit the symfony controller? Only then you can access the DIC via $this->get()

Answer (score 0):

Add the use statement atop your controller class and then modify your controller to extend it:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class YourController extends Controller
{
  // ...
}
```

That's it! You now have access to methods like `$this->get()` or `$this->render()` and many others.

Comment: thanks it was a lack of concentration, i fixed the problem with mr.void , thank you too for answering the question .